# How to improve a monthly usage quota system for an API with growing number of users?

Tags: architecture, api-design, software-as-a-service, scaling

Couple of years ago, I designed an API service which has a limit on the number of requests per month per user. To track the monthly usage of each user, I used a table called `monthly_usage`. The table structure is as follows:

| Column name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | integer | A unique identifier for the user |
| current_period_start | timestamp | The start time of the current monthly usage period |
| current_period_end | timestamp | The end time of the current monthly usage period |
| total_requests | integer | The total number of requests made by the user in the period |

Whenever a request is served, an event is fired and the user details are used to increment a counter in Redis called `current_count`. Every 10 minutes, a schedule called `usage_collection_job` is executed, which performs the following steps:

1. Collect the `current_count` value for each user from Redis.
2. Add the `current_count` value to the corresponding `total_requests` value in the `monthly_usage` table.
3. Reset `current_count` in Redis to zero.
4. Store the updated `total_requests` value in Redis under the key `current_total`.

Whenever a new request is received, a `UsageFilter` queries the `current_total` from Redis and verifies that the user hasn't exceeded their quota. If the user has exceeded their quota, the filter rejects the request. At the end of each month (or when the subscription renews), the `monthly_usage` for each user is reset to zero.

This system has been working well, but as the number of users is growing (over 10000 in last few months alone), I'm facing the following issues:

- The `usage_collection_job` is taking more and more time to complete execution, which is affecting the API performance.
- Since this job runs for all users at the same time, it causes high CPU usage and spikes in Redis usage.
- Since the `current_total` is updated only every 10 minutes, a user can exceed their quota and still send thousands of requests before the usage limit is enforced.

I'm looking for suggestions to improve the current system and overcome these limitations. Specifically, I'm interested in:

- Ways to optimize the `usage_collection_job` to improve performance.
- Alternatives to the current system that can handle a growing number of users and requests more efficiently.
- Ways to enforce the usage limit more frequently or in real-time to prevent users from exceeding their quota.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Work out the count of requests from a time indexed log of requests instead of storing a number in reddis. (elastic etc)

   Now you are just writing to the log for each request.
2. Move your usage collection job to work off the log instead of the live value.

   This removes any impact on the API from running the job.
3. Only check users that are near their limit

   Have the collection job mark users that are X away from hitting their limit, or be clever and predict for their usage when they are likely to run out. Mark these users to check and have a more frequent collection job that updates their status more frequently.
4. Dont query the current total in the API.

   Instead, prevent the user logging in/refreshing their token when they have exceeded their limit. This removes the performance impact of checking the user data on each call.

   If its critical to lock users out immediately you could have a 'hot list' of active users that have just been locked out in a hashmap or similar and check that. Hopefully the number will be small as they will have to have gone over their limit less than token expiration time ago.